# grep behaving differently in bash script than in interactive shell

Tags: bash, shell, grep

In my bash script, I am attempting to parse through a status file and detect errors based on some keywords. I store these prefixes in a list, and then loop through them.

**Bash script:**

```
status_page="/path/to/file.txt"
list="aaa bbb ccc ddd"

for pre in $list
do
    echo "grep '\w\w\w${pre}-.*\.lin failed' ${status_page}" # debug
    if grep '\w\w\w${pre}-.*\.lin failed' ${status_page}; then
        echo "Found error!"
        exit 8;
    fi
done
```

**/path/to/file.txt:**

```
xyzfff-tool.lin failed
xyzggg-exec.lin failed
rstccc-tool.lin failed
```

The bash script should catch the line `rstccc-tool.lin failed`, but it skips right over it.

For debugging, I print the grep commands verbatim, and when I copy that line and issue the command in my shell (tcsh), it returns that line...

**Shell:**

```
$ grep '\w\w\wccc-.*\.lin failed' /path/to/file.txt
    rstccc-tool.lin failed
$ echo $?
0
```

If grep can find the line when I issue the command normally, how come it won't find it when the bash script is calling grep?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable won't be expanded in single quotes. Try with double quotes:

```
if grep "\w\w\w${pre}-.*\.lin failed" "${status_page}"; then
```

Comment: Sure enough... that solved it all. Thanks for the quick solution. :) Will accept the answer in... 9 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

The ${pre} portion of that script is not parsing it correctly. I believe you need that line to say:

```
if grep '\w\w\w'${pre}'-.*\.lin failed' ${status_page}; then
```

... where the ${pre} is outside the quotation, such that bash will do the correct string replacement before sending it to grep.